# EDIT: Can cdf have a set of continuity points which is a.s. different from $\emptyset$?

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, cumulative-distribution-functions

It can be easily proven that a cumulative distribution function (cdf)
$$F(x)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\le x\right)\hspace{0.3cm}\text{for }-\infty<x<+\infty$$
is right-continuous $\left(\text{that is }F(x)=F(x^+)\right)$, but NOT left-continuous $\left(\text{that is }F(x)\neq F(x^-)\right)$.

Given this, could it be even possible that there exists a set of continuity points of $F$ 
$$D=\{x: F(x^-)=F(x)\}$$ 
which is a.s. different from $\emptyset$? **(That is, considering $\mathbb{P}$ as the probability measure corresponding to the cdf $F$, $\mathbb{P}(D\neq\emptyset)=0$)**. 
Clearly, for $D$ it would be sufficient to specify the left-continuity condition, since, as above-stated, right-continuity is already granted by definition of cdf. 
However, the **question** is: *could one have that such a D is a.s. different from $\emptyset$ if cumulative distribution functions are known to be not left-continous at any points at all?*

Comment: Do you know that $F(x^{-})$ exists for every $x$? What is wrong with the definition of $D$?

Comment: Yeah, of course it exists for every $x$. However, since by definition of cdf $F$, $F(x)\neq F(x^-) \forall x$, such a set of continuity points $D$ (such that also $F(x)=F(x^-)$ holds true) would be of measure $0$. Isn't it of measure $0$? I have also edited my question @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $D^{\complement}$ of discontinuity points is a countable set.

This becomes clear if we write $D^{\complement}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ where $E_n=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid F(x)-F(x^-)>\frac1{n}\}$.

Observe that for every $n$ the fact $P(E_n)\leq1$ tells us that the set $E_n$ has less than $n$ elements.

Comment: However, on my textbook it is stated that $D$ is "the set of continuity points of $F$", since - I guess - in the definition of $D$ it is implicit that $F(x^+)=F(x)$, that is $D$ can be defined as $$D=\{x: F(x^-)=F(x)\text{ AND } F(x^+)=F(x)\}$$
I have tried to render this with the statement "Clearly, for $D$ it would be sufficient to specify the left-continuity condition, since, as above-stated, right-continuity is already granted by definition of cdf" in my question. **[CONTINUE]** @drhab

Comment: **[CONTINUE]** So, given that $D$ is the set of continuity points of $F$, since $F$ is right-continous but not left- continuous (hence, NOT continuous), could I say that $D$ it is almost surely an empty set? That is, that $\mathbb{P}(D\neq\emptyset)=0$? @drhab

Comment: I thought you were speaking of *discontinuity* points (sorry) and have adapted the notation in my answer. The only thing I am saying is that the set of discontinuity points is countable. Consequently it has Lebesgue measure $0$ and the set of continuity points is the complement of a countable set (so has Lebesgue measure $+\infty$). Statements like $\mathbb P(D\neq\varnothing)=0$ only make sense if there is a probability measure $\mathbb P$ is defined on sets. If you start with a CDF $F$ then the corresponding set $D$ is a *fixed* set.

Comment: Here, why can't we say that there is a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ defined on the set $D$? Thank you a lot and sorry for all these questions @drhab

Comment: Which probability measure do you have in mind then? The one that corresponds with CDF $F$ maybe?

Comment: Yes, exactly that one @drhab

Comment: But then only expressions like $\mathbb P(D)$ make sense. Not expressions like $\mathbb P(D\neq\varnothing)$. For the second thing $D$ must be defined as a function on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ that sends each $\omega$ to a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry, I'm not a mathematician, hence I know my reasonings are very error-prone. Just to clarify, what I meant (in rough manner) is that... **if I know that, by its own nature, a certain function is NOT continuous (that is, for example, is right-continuous but not left-continuous, as for $F$), what can I say about its set of continuity points?** Naively, I would say that it has no elements, since there are no continuity points for a function which is NOT continuous by def.. Where is the flaw of my reasoning? If it is correct instead, how to express it mathematically? @drhab

Comment: A function is continuous iff it is continuous at *every* point of its domain. In other words: iff its set of continuity points *is* its domain. A function is not continuous iff the negation of that is true which means that its set of continuity points is *not* its domain. But that does not imply that the set of continuity points is empty. It is enough already if only point is not in this set.

Comment: Ok, so I deduce that a function which is not continuous can although have some continuity points. Where could I find some reference to an example of a function which is not continuous whose set of continuity points is not empty? @drhab

Comment: The indicator function of set $[0,\infty)$ is not continuous (point $0$ is not a continuity point) and its set of continuity points is $\mathbb R-\{0\}\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you$^{\infty}$ (hahah) for your patience and kindness and for all your time. Very grateful :) @drhab

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is precisely the set of points at which $F$ is  continuous.

Any monotone function $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has at most countable number of discontinuity points. Hence $D^{c}$ is necessarily at most countable. Every countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$. Hence $D^{c}$ has measure $0$. Since the measure of the real line is $\infty$ this implies that the measure of $D$ is necessarily $\infty$.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. On my textbook $D$ is instead defined as *"the set of continuity points of $F$"*, since I think that $F(x)=F(x^+)$ is implicit in the definition of $D$. That is, in a most complete fashion, $D$ could be defined as 
$$D=\{x:F(x^-)=F(x)\text{ AND } F(x^+)=F(x)\}$$ Henceforth, given that $D$ is the set of continuity points of $F$, could I keep on stating that, by definition of cdf $F$, it has measure $0$? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Answer edited. The measure of $D$ is always $\infty$!

Comment: Just one last thing: could I also state that $\mathbb{P}\left(D\neq \emptyset\right)=0$. That is, in other terms, that $D=\emptyset$ almost surely? Thank you a lot @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: $D$ can be empty or non-empty depending on $F$. But you cannot talk about $P(D \neq \emptyset)$. $D \neq \emptyset$ is just statement. It is not  measurable set for which you can assign a probability or a measure. @Strictly_increasing